# Return multiple models from a view in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am learning Django,

I am having a problem with fetching data from 2 different models with the same view.

My models are as follow :

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Destination(models.Model):
    roadtripname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        self.roadtripname

@python_2_unicode_compatible        
class Trajectories(models.Model):
    roadtripname = models.ForeignKey(Destination, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    place_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.place_text
```

my view class is this :

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'roadtrip/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'roadtrip_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Destination.objects.filter()
```

my html is :

```
{% for roadtrip in roadtrip_list %}
    {{ roadtrip.roadtripname }} 
{% endfor %}
```

I have tried to return my 2 models like this :

```
return Destination.objects.filter(), Trajectories.objects.filter()
```

and then in html doing

```
{% for roadtrip in roadtrip_list[0] %}
    {{ roadtrip.roadtripname }} 
{% endfor %}
```

but this does not work, I do not know how to be able to access both the Destination and Trajectories models. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can't, get queryset should do one thing, and that is to return **one** queryset. What are you actually trying to do though? show a destinations trajectories or show all of both model? (both well documented)

Comment: I have a select button where I chose the destination, then later in my code I want to retrieve the trajectories linked with the destination id. I was thinking that if I can return both models, I could just loop through the data from the second set(trajectories) and save in an javascript array when it's equal to the select value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could just loop through the data from the second set(trajectories) and save in an javascript array when it's equal to the select value.

You *could* but that is just awful and you're just opening yourself up to allow a client to modify something that they really don't need to.

With every django many-to-x relationship you can find all objects related to another with `_set` so just keep your initial `get_queryset` the same (returning destination) and then get trajectories for each object.

```
{% for roadtrip in roadtrip_list %}
    {% for trajectory in roadtrip.trajectories_set.all %}
          {# Use trajectories #}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ roadtrip.roadtripname }} 
{% endfor %}
```

<sub><sub><sub>*I'm aware there are very simple optimizations that could be made here for performance improvements but I'm intentionally not including them</sub></sub></sub>